# How do I make a navigation drawer in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

How do I make a drawer in react native? Dependencies in my package.json is like this

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/samples": "~36.0.0",
"@expo/vector-icons": "~10.0.0",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.0.5",
"@react-navigation/web": "~1.0.0-alpha.9",
"expo": "~36.0.0",
"expo-asset": "~8.0.0",
"expo-constants": "~8.0.0",
"expo-font": "~8.0.0",
"expo-web-browser": "~8.0.0",
"galio-framework": "^0.6.3",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~1.4.0",
"react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
"react-navigation": "~4.0.10",
"react-navigation-stack": "~1.10.3",
"react-navigation-tabs": "~2.6.2"
},
```

I have made a Drawer.js file like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/Accountant/HomeScreen';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

  </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MyDrawer;
```

My Header.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button } from 'galio-framework';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <Block style={ styles.header }>
        <Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="grey" onPress={() => this.props.navigator.openDrawer()}/>
        <Text style={ styles.title }>{ props.title }</Text>
    </Block>
  )
}
```

My AccountantScreen.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button } from 'galio-framework';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../../common/Header';
import Drawer from '../../common/Drawer';

class Accountant extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <Block style={ styles.blockStyle }>
        <Header title="Accounts" />
        <Drawer />
        <Text>Accountant Screen</Text>
    </Block>
  );
  }
}

export default Accountant;
```

I have made a HomeScreen.js like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button } from 'galio-framework';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <Block style={ styles.blockStyle }>

        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </Block>
  );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I know there are some mistakes in my code. I am new to react native. 
I have a header in AccountantScreen.js. When I click the menu icon in the header, the drawer should open. But it's not opening.

This is my whole code in github: 
    https://github.com/boidurja/smartcope.git

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this out**

My Header.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Block, Input, Button } from 'galio-framework';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <Block style={ styles.header }>
        <Ionicons name="md-menu" size={32} color="grey" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
        <Text style={ styles.title }>{ props.title }</Text>
    </Block>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Could there be a problem in Drawer.js?